# Поставить фильтр на вложенное поле сериализатора DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, сериализация, django-filter

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я создаю api приложение , у меня есть модель магазина, в сериализаторе которого я добавила вложенное поле, ссылающееся на другой сериализатор. Теперь мне нужно добавить фильтр на поле из вложенного сериализатора , но у меня никак не получается. Я попробовала просто добавить поле в фильтры в контроллере , пробовала добавить отдельный класс сериализатор для фильтрации и вызвать этот сериализатор в list_serializer_class в мета классе своего серилизатора , все безрезультатно. Я хочу чтобы при запросе на список магазина, пользователь мог ввести название страны, что-то вроде этого: «url+?country=Россия». Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении мне двигаться, документацию прочитала не нашла ответа.

Это мои модели:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Retail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='компания')
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='название магазина')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='поставщик')
    debt_to_supplier = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Задолженность перед поставщиком в RUB')
    creating_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='дата создания', default=now)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.store_name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'магазин'
        verbose_name_plural = 'магазины'


class Contacts(models.Model):
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=150, verbose_name='почта')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='страна')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='город')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='улица')
    house_num = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='номер дома')
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='магазин')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.mail}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'контакт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'контакты'
```

Это сериализаторы:

```
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = '__all__'

class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contacts = ContactsSerializer(source='contacts_set', read_only=True, many=True)
    products = ProductsSerializer(source='products_set', read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ['company_name', 'store_name', 'contacts', 'products', 'debt_to_supplier', 'creating_date']
```

Это контроллер:

```
class StoreListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer
    pagination_class = StorePaginator
    permission_classes = [UserPermissionsAll]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете всё же использовать фильтр:

viewset:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class StoreListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer
    pagination_class = StorePaginator
    permission_classes = [UserPermissionsAll]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    # Думаю, что сработает такого плана запрос:
    filterset_fields = ['contacts_set__country',]
```

Попробуйте отправить такой запрос:  «url+?contacts_set__country=Россия»

При желании, вы можете изменить имя query-параметра и написать свой фильтр-класс, который преобразует, например, country в contacts_set__country.

Comment: Добрый вечер, спасибо большое за ответ, все получилось, только без _set, в фильтре Я написала ['contacts__country'] .